# Bash script - grouping arguments into a single argument

Tags: bash

I want to make a bash script to search web from command line. But I don't want to need to put quotes in the search string. I want to search like this:

```
search hello world
```

The problem is that I need to put double quotes in the url address because it will contain spaces if there are more than one term in the search.

So I tried:

```
#/bin/sh
firefox "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=$@\"
```

but I got two pages open, one with: `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hello` and another with `mundo`

On the other hand, If I use simple quotes instead, I get: `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=$@`

This works fine:

```
#/bin/sh
firefox "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hello world"
```

but useless...

Comment: `$@` does some magic when quoted. Use `$*` instead: `firefox "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=$*"`. (URL-encoding notwithstanding.)

Comment: The whole point of using `"$@"` instead of `"$*"` is that the former breaks the word into multiple pieces.  If you don't want it to be split, use `"$*"`

Comment: Voting to close as a typo. Glad  you solved your problem. Good luck.